# VS 2010 XAML debugging got stuck on breakpoint

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, xaml, visual-studio-debugging

I am trying to debug into xaml in silverlight 5 project. When debugger hits a breakpoint it correctly stops, I can read binding properties, but I can`t continue.

When I hit the continue button, button turns to gray and nothing happens. All debugger buttons are inactive. The only way to stop is to close the solution. While closing solution many error messages pup up saying: "Source file XY does not belong to the project being debugged."

There is no problem with debugging in C# only in XAML.

Any help will be greatly accepted.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the .suo solution user file, which may have become corrupt. Back it up first ;-)